# Given an unknown square matrix $H$ and known vectors $x$ and $y$, is it possible to find $H$ if $H\vec{x}=\vec{y}$?

Tags: matrix-equations

If $H\vec{x}=\vec{y}$ can we find $H$ by inverting $\vec{x}$? No idea how to invert $\vec{x}$ though or if this equation is even solvable.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Given you are in a flight (unknown) can you say it will take you from your current location (known) to Tokyo? Your question can be considered equivalent to this one in some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H_{ij}$ denote the elements of the $m\times n$-matrix $H$. Then you are asking to solutions of the following linear system of equations:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n H_{1k}x_k = y_1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n H_{2k}x_k = y_2$$

and so on, with the final equation being

$$\sum_{k=1}^n H_{mk}x_k = y_m$$

Obviously, we have $n\times m$ unknown elements (the entries of the matrix $H$) and only $m$ equations. This is, in general, not solveable uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

For every vector $\vec{x}$ exist a *non zero* vector $\vec{z}$ such that $\vec x \cdot\vec z=0$. Then we can build a new matrix $K$ with as many rows as number of $\vec y$ coordinates and each row of $K$ coincides with $\vec z$. Then
$$
K\vec x=0\\
(H+K)\vec x=\vec y\\
H+K\neq H
$$
then your statement is false because for every $\vec x, \vec y$ there aren't a single $H$ (there're infinitely many of them).

For example
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\\
\vec x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2
\end{array}\right)\\
\vec y=\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\
2
\end{array}\right)\\
\vec z=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\\
-1
\end{array}\right)\\
K=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -1\\
2 & -1
\end{array}\right)\\
H+K=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0\\
2 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
(H+K)\vec x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\
2
\end{array}\right)=\vec y
$$